# backing up RDS to non AWS backup solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, backup

We have a regulatory requirement to backup RDS to non AWS backup solution. Current backup solution is Acronis but it does not have native RDS connectivity. We also do not want to backup to S3 and then backup outside AWS. Looking for a solution which allows backup without many moving parts. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws